# Swift replacement for RestKit

Tags: ios, json, swift, rest, restkit

do you know any good alternative for RestKit that could be used in Swift projects?
I would like to have possibility to create request and response models, define their mappings (or it could happen automatically?), so I could get responses directly as desired objects.

Core Data integration is not essential, but would be nice to have.

Thank you for your help!